# I want to create AFTER UPDATE trigger to update DATE OF BIRTH where (AGE < 20)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to update the data in table where age is less than 20. So I want to update dob and set it to date where age is greater than 20 (by using after update trigger). I know what I'm saying doesn't make any sense but this is the task given by my proffesor.

and I'm using Oracle Live SQL.

```
create table SYCS_DBMS(
    SID NUMBER(10),
    SNAME VARCHAR(50),
    DOB DATE,
    PRESENT DATE
);

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY';

INSERT INTO SYCS_DBMS VALUES(1, 'ANKIT', '4-OCTOBER-2002', sysdate);
INSERT INTO SYCS_DBMS VALUES(2, 'AAKASH', '30-OCTOBER-2002', sysdate);
INSERT INTO SYCS_DBMS VALUES(3, 'DHRUV', '5-APRIL-2002', sysdate);
INSERT INTO SYCS_DBMS VALUES(4, 'DEERAJ', '5-AUGUST-2002', sysdate);
INSERT INTO SYCS_DBMS VALUES(5, 'ADIL', '11-MARCH-2003', sysdate);
INSERT INTO SYCS_DBMS VALUES(6, 'VIRAJ', '7-JULY-2002', sysdate);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trUPDT
AFTER UPDATE
ON SYCS_DBMS
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
STU_AGE NUMBER;
BEGIN
--TO CHECK THE AGE BY DATE OF BIRTH
SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY'), TO_DATE(:NEW.DOB,'DD-MON-YYYY'))/12
INTO STU_AGE FROM DUAL;
END;
```

Comment: Calculate the date 20 years ago. Then set `DOB` to `LEAST(:NEW.DOB, DATE_20_YR_AGO)`

Comment: "... *update* the data in table where *age is less than 20*" and "... *update* dob and set it to date where *age is greater than 20*" sounds contradictory. Please, describe what is the input data, what actions should be performed and what you expect to be the result data.

Comment: Your date format is off: if the template is `DD-MON-YYYY` then the value should have a 2-digit day and a 3-character month, like `04-OCT-2002`. Also, I would do this as a _BEFORE INSERT_ trigger (your example doesn't actually do any updates!): modify the `DOB` value as part of the original SQL insert instead of executing multiple extra steps to change the original value after it has already been applied. The result should be faster/more scalable.

Comment: `sysdate` and `dob` is of type `date`, so `to_date` function is superfluous here. You do not need to convert a date into a date.

Comment: @astentx - applying to_date to a DATE is worse than merely superfluous. It forces an implied TO_CHAR, which in turn relies on the controlling setting of NLS_DATE_FORMAT.  If the  stars don't line up perfectly, it will result in an error, not just extra, unneeded work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a walk down "Revision Lane" as this code can make use of some. But first as work about formatting. You need to *learn how to do it*. In fact I tell my students that if they submit unformatted code they fail that assignment.  I don not even bother to read it. **Format your code**. I should be able to get an idea of the flow just looking at it. It does not really matter how you format, just as long as it consistent through out. Admittedly it is not a big deal for 10 lines of code, but the time to form good habits is before forming bad ones.  Now for what you have:  

Be careful setting and depending on setting NLS_DATE_FORMAT for here
it is fine. But what happens when you need to call another routine
an that developer also sets NLS_DATE_FORMAT but different from yours.  

Once a column/parameter is a `date` data type never use the to_date function on it, it is already a date. Oracle provides a slew of date processing functions and makes date arithmetic available. In this case both sysdate and the column DOB are already dates so do not do to_date() on them.

```
Your expression 

    months_between(to_date(sysdate,'dd-mon-yyyy'),
                   to_date(:new.dob,'dd-mon-yyyy'))/12

Becomes just simply 

    months_between(sysdate, :new.dob)/12
```

Going a step further. Within a plsql block there is no need to `Select ... into` unless you are actually retrieving from a table (or view, etc). You can just make a direct assignment to a variable.
So with this and the above:

```
   select months_between(to_date(sysdate, :new.dob)/12
     into stu_age 
     from dual; 
     
becomes a simple assignment:
    
    stu_age := months_between(to_date(sysdate, :new.dob)/12;
```

At this point your trigger has been reduced to:

```
create or replace trigger trupdt
    after update
       on sycs_dbms
      for each row
declare 
    stu_age number;
begin 
    --to check the age by date of birth
    stu_age := months_between(sysdate,:new.dob)/12; 
end trupdt;
```

Unfortunately, it is completely useless. You computed the months between the 2 dates as a numeric value (with decimal places), but then the trigger ends and just throws that calculation away doing nothing with it. I do not think this is what you after. You initially stated you wanted to **update dob**. Well there are 2 issues here.

1. DOB is defined as a `date` so your calculation needs to result in a date. This does not.
2. You have a *after update* trigger but an after update trigger
   **cannot change** column values, You need a *before update* trigger.

Now you could the calculated value and a date calculation to get the DOB value, with the appropriate logic to determine if you even should. But the suggestion by @Barmar is extremely good. I'll us it. Thanks Barmer. Instead of the months_between function use the *add_months* function with sysdate to calculate the date 20 years ago, then use the *least* function to choose the appropriate value. Also make a direct assignment to `:new_dob` bypassing the local variable. The final trigger for this becomes simply:

```
create or replace trigger sycs_dbms_dob_ge20_bur
   before update
       on sycs_dbms
      for each row
begin
    :new.dob := least(:new.dob, add_months(sysdate, -240)); -- (20yrs * 12mon/yr)    
end sycs_dbms_dob_ge20_bur;
```

I have put together a fiddle here that walks through each step above. I would not typically provide a complete answer to an obvious homework assignment. But if I had assigned this I would have walked through it in the next class. My hope is you take this to class and discuss it the professor and other students. Do not just submit as your own, any half-way decent professor would catch on real fast. But at least study carefully what it does and how it got there from where you started.

Comment: Thanks for you help I really appreciate it. I lack programming logic so I was having hard time understanding what is the actual question and how to approach it . I am not gonna copy paste this  code in my homework but I will try to understand logic and apply it to solve other problems .